# Customizing Woocommerce email notification when order is pending payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have found a partial and workable answer to my question in this related answer: 
[send-an-email-notification-when-order-status-changhe-fron-pendig-to-cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732404/send-an-email-notification-when-order-status-change-from-pending-to-cancelled/47210706#47210706)

I'm thinking to use the solution provided but would like to see if I could change the email notification to clearly say "pending payment order now canceled" so it differs from the regular canceled orders.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this that will customize the heading and the subject of this email:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_cancelled', 'cancelled_send_an_email_notification', 10, 2 );
function cancelled_send_an_email_notification( $order_id, $order ){
    // Getting all WC_emails objects
    $email_notifications = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Cancelled Order email notification
    $email_obj = $email_notifications['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order'];

    // Customizing heading and subject
    $email_obj->settings['heading'] = __( "Pending payment order now Cancelled", "woocommerce" );
    $email_obj->settings['subject'] = __( "[{site_title}] Pending payment order ({order_number}), now Cancelled", "woocommerce" );

    // Sending the email
    $email_obj->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

Comment: Wonderful! Works great. Thank you very much Loic for all your help.